# State the condition which must be met for a puck to lose contact with a surface and use this to show the vertical height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction

Consider a small friction-less puck perched at the top of a sphere of radius R. The puck is given a small nudge (negligible initial velocity) and begins to slide down. State the condition which must be met for the puck to lose contact with the surface of the sphere and use this condition to show the vertical height h through which the puck will descend before losing contact is given by h = R/3 .

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Basically, the puck will be on the sphere till it has some normal force(contact force).you can equate the centripetal force $mv^2/R=mg\cos \theta -N$ where $\theta$ is the vertical angle made by the center of the sphere with the puck.

You can also use the conservation of energy that $K.E=P.E$ and solve for $N$ and $h$ (note that $\cos\theta$ can be calculated in terms of $R$ and $h$).

Find the $h$ for $N=0$.

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions